# Syntax Error in Apt in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, apt, dpkg

This is the error I get when I try to install any thing using apt or apt-get.

```
/usr/bin/apt: 1: /usr/bin/apt: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
```

what does it mean by Syntax error?. Which file should I see to correct this?.

I tried to see the version of apt by command

```
dpkg -l | grep apt | head -n 1
```

Output :

```
 iU  apt:amd64  1.2.29  amd64 commandline package manager
```

If I try to execute any of these binary by .**/apt**

```
bash: ./apt: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
```

Getting Some error like this

```
srushti@srushti-X556UQK:/$ sudo apt-get install --reinstall apt

/usr/bin/apt-get: 1: /usr/bin/apt-get: ELF: not found
/usr/bin/apt-get: 1: /usr/bin/apt-get: @8�@8: not found
/usr/bin/apt-get: 2: /usr/bin/apt-get: ����: not found
/usr/bin/apt-get: 3: /usr/bin/apt-get: : not found
/usr/bin/apt-get: 3: /usr/bin/apt-get: cannot open ½���������hI��p�: No such file
rm�: not foundet: 3: /usr/bin/apt-get: c
    /usr/bin/apt-get: 4: /usr/bin/apt-get: �7��: not found
�F�'�: /usr/bin/apt-get: 
                   �
                     �J
n\����          \
Y[#��   �d��=
           �: not found
/usr/bin/apt-get: 6: /usr/bin/apt-get: �C��+: not found
/usr/bin/apt-get: 16: /usr/bin/apt-get: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
```

Comment: try `sudo apt-get install --reinstall apt` and you can use apt-get to update or whatever you need to install until you get apt working

Comment: Getting the same errors

Comment: I suspect your question would be easier to read if you provided commands & responses. eg. why would `apt` be in your $PWD (current directory; ie. `./apt` runs apt in your current directory).  If you check file-type `file /usr/bin/apt` what do you get?   and have you made changes to python by chance?